# html code doesn't work in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

this following code belongs to a wordpress custom plugin "upload". It basically creates a button to open a file browser to select one file.

```
<form class="file_input_uploadform" id="uploadform_2" name="uploadform_2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input align="center" type="button" id="input_2" value="Select File" class="file_input_button_hover">
                            <input type="file" accept=".$params[" pid"]="" "="" class="file_input_hidden" name="uploadedfile_2" id="upfile_2" tabindex="1" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName_2').value = this.value.replace(/c:\\fakepath\\/i, '');" onmouseout="javascript: document.getElementById('input_2').className = 'file_input_button'" onmouseover="javascript: document.getElementById('input_2').className = 'file_input_button_hover'" onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('messagelabel_2').innerHTML = ''; document.getElementById('inline_upload_message_2').style.display='none'; this.value = ''; document.getElementById('fileName_2').value = '';">
                            <input type="hidden" id="hiddeninput_2" name="hiddeninput_2" value="">
                        </form>
```

if we put it in a html editor, it works fine --- click on the button will pop up the file browser.

However if we put it in wordpress with

```
....
[upload uploadId="0"]
[upload uploadId="1"]
....
```

The first one doesn't work (didn't open the file browser) while the second one works(opens the file browser).

Is it any way to debug, or is it any reason why this would happen?

Comment: Isn't `[upload uploadId="0"]` a shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Search inside plugin's code for `upload` and you should find something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'upload', 'upload_function' );
```

Then search for `upload_function` (or whatever the name of the function is). Then check what parameters the function accepts and how it works.

That way you shall find why this function doesn't accept `0` for `uploadId`.

More on Shortcodes: [Wordpress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Interestingly, even if I ....
[upload uploadId="1"]
[upload uploadId="2"]
....It still doesn't work. It is not about the parameter, but is about the first one doesn't work but later ones work...